# VS Cloud Code extension writing Python libraries to AppData/Local/Temp every time a workspace is opened

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, windows-10, vscode-extensions, google-cloud-code

With Cloud Code Extension enabled, every time I open a workspace (new or existing) VSCode spins up two Python tasks each taking up 10% cpu each for at least 5 minutes.  Each task is going to C:\Users{userid}\AppData\Local\Temp and creating a new folder named tmp******/python and writing all this data (python libraries).  The extension does this everytime I open a workspace, resulting in close to 100 of these tmp directories on my disk.

Also I'm not doing any python related dev or have any other python related extensions.  I confirmed Cloud Code is the culprit via disabling the extension.

Does anyone know the purpose of this, and how to disable it w/o completely disabling the extension?

I'm on Windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Cloud Code installing and updating the Google Cloud CLI.  This includes a bunch of python files and they precompile on first use. As you already discovered this is controlled by the `cloudcode.autodependencies` setting, you can set this to off and have Cloud Code utilize that install from the system path.  This is covered in the docs under https://cloud.google.com/code/docs/vscode/install#custom_versions_of_dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

The setting seems to be

```
"cloudcode.autoDependencies": "off"
```

Not sure what effect turning this off will have but it does seem to stop the obnoxious startup cost of opening a workspace with this extension enabled